# yarn add @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb

Tags: aws-sdk, yarnpkg

I am learning how to use aws-sdk version 3. AWS document says that to import the modular package from version 3 we have to use below command:

```
yarn add @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb
```

I do not understand this yarn command, because my understanding is that @ is a special character and has to be used to specify version of a specific package e.g. `yarn add packagename@version`. Can we have also package name starting from @?

Also when I run the command `yarn add @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb`, I get by default version 3.3.0. How can I specify a specific version (e.g. 3.0.0) in the above command.

In yarn registry the latest version `yarn add aws-sdk` is 2.8. So does this mean that there is no way to  add full package of aws-sdk v3, and only way is to go module by module?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's a *scoped* package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb. 2. With *another* `@`: `@scope/package@version`.

Comment: Many Thanks All, this was very helpful , though will  still do my research on for aws-sdk v3 how can i install teh whole library, because as of now it seems only way is to go with its modular structure and install componment by componenet.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the features they explicitly call out: [*"has a modular architecture with a separate package for each service"*](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3). The old way meant you had a lot of unused code for the services you didn't use.